# Automatic Hyperlinks within Excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I want excel to automatically create hyperlinks to another cell. I have one column with different strings and when i type the name of one of the existings strings in another column i want a hyperlink to the cell in the first column automatically. Is this possible and how would you then do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using VSTO:

Declare SortedList Object in ThisAddin to keep Keywords and Range Address

```
Dim keywordList As New SortedList(Of String, String)
```

In Application.SheetChange can you catch the string you typed.
You can use Target.Value and Target.Address.

Look up for Target.Value in the SortedList. If nothing found add new entry to the list with value and range address.
if entry is already declared get the address from the list and create Hyperlink for Target

```
Public Sub Application_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) Handles Application.SheetChange
   Dim value As String = CStr(Target.Value) 
   If liste.ContainsKey(value) Then
       Dim address As String = String.Empty
       keywordList.TryGetValue(value, address)
       If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then
           Target.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(Target, address)
       End If
   Else
      keywordList.Add(CStr(Target.Value), CStr(Target.Address))
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but it could make the job:

1. Assuming you have a file named "test.xlsx"
2. In column "A" write your strings
3. In column "C" write string you want to make hypertext link
4. In column "D" write `=MATCH(C2;A:A;0)`
5. In column "E" write `=HYPERLINK("[test.xlsx]A"&D2;"GO TO "&C2)`

Points 4 and 5 could by merged into one formula.

[image: Ilustrating picture]

The difference between your description and my solution is that I construct hyperlink in adjacent cell (not the cell you write search string into)